# JQT gotofunction problem

Tags: jqtouch, goto

i am trying to use the goTo function to switch between different divs.
but in the function goTo(id,animation)
it is not going to that id.
Can anyone please help me with this problem.

Thanks,

Devan

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to diagnose without looking at your code. I have a few ideas, but it would be best if you were to share the problematic section of your code for others to investigate.

A few questions/ideas:

1) Check to ensure you have not used the same div ID more than once.

2) Have you been able to successfully use the goTo function at all?

3) Can you create a basic HTML page that uses this function successfully?

4) What version of jQTouch are you using? Does the goTo function work once, and then freeze every time afterwards? I [reported a bug](https://github.com/senchalabs/jQTouch/issues/197) regarding this behavior a while ago. Not sure if it's been resolved yet, but you could see if an older version of jQTouch might help.

---

Again, without examples of your code... I'm taking wild guesses. Consider sharing the problematic section and someone might be able to pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put animation, without animation worked for me...

eg..

jQT.goTo('#rest');